# Missing div area while repeat

Tags: php, html, css

i have a problem with my stylesheet.
i have repeated div by looping (php)
[image]

This is the looping

```
<div class=content>
    <?php $db=new db; $sql=$db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_news WHERE category='1' ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 0,10"); while($r=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ echo '
    <div class=box-thread>
        <img src="images/galleries/preview_'.$r['img'].'">
        <br />
        <h1>'.$r['title'].'</h1>

        <p align=justify>'.strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode(substr($r['contents'],0,200))).'</p>
    </div>'; } ?>
</div>
```

but the problem is showed in the picture, there is missing div there. I dont know why. any div i set to "float:left" so it's auto go to bottom if there is reach the page's width. 
This is my css

```
.content {
    width:100%;
    margin:auto
}
.box-thread {
    width:20%;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin:2%;
    float:left;
    min-width:240px
}
.box-thread img {
    width:100%;
} 
.box-thread p {
    padding:5px 20px
}
.box-thread h1 {
    padding:0 20px;
    font-size:18px
}
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Your fifth div can't clear the first div so you need to either do it manually or think of another approach.

Comment: One thing i can see is that in you HTML you need to put quotes around your box-thread class. Like this <div class="box-thread"> same with the justify class.

Comment: so, i have to put "clear:both" like that? *sorry for my bad english. I hope u understand

Comment: Remove the float and change to `.box-thread { display: inline-block; }`. That way, all divs are in the same line, and the line wraps to the next line, no problem.

Comment: thank u GolezTrol.. u save my night..

Comment: 1 more question. After i use GolezTrol's suggestion, now my div inline in the bottom. What if i want to inline at the top?

Comment: The cause of the problem, by the way, was the difference in height of the boxes. The first one is slightly higher. So when the fifth one doesn't fit, after the fourth, it tries to move down, under the fourth, and left under third and second because they are less high than the fourth. The first one is higher, so the fifth one gets stuck on the edge of that extra height.

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top` to the box to make them align to the top of the line.

Comment: and if i want to put them in dinamyc (zigzag top and bottom) is it possible? I mean, there is no inline top or bottom. The div just appear where it should be

Comment: vertical-align: top | middle | bottom